# Lock DragMove inside of an area | only horizontal vertical movement | DragMove Preview Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `WindowContainer` class where all `ChildWindows` gets automatically registered. The idea is, all `ChildWindows` are "locked" inside of the `WindowContainer` and you cannot move/drag them outside of this area.

`ChildWindow` inherits from `Window`.

I have already a solution where it is working:

#### C# Snippet

```
// Events

private void ChildWindow_OnLocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    _CheckBounds(sender as HtChildWindow);
}

private void ChildWindow_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs sizeChangedEventArgs)
{
    _CheckBounds(sender as HtChildWindow);
}

// Private Methods

private void _CheckBounds(HtChildWindow window)
{
    Rect trueWindowContainer = WindowContainer.TransformToAncestor(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), WindowContainer.RenderSize));

    if (window.Left < trueWindowContainer.X)
        window.Left = trueWindowContainer.X;
    if (window.Top < trueWindowContainer.Y)
        window.Top = trueWindowContainer.Y;
    if (window.Left + window.ActualWidth > trueWindowContainer.X + trueWindowContainer.Width)
        window.Left = (trueWindowContainer.X + trueWindowContainer.Width) - window.ActualWidth;
    if (window.Top + window.ActualHeight > trueWindowContainer.Y + trueWindowContainer.Height)
        window.Top = (trueWindowContainer.Y + trueWindowContainer.Height) - window.ActualHeight;            
}
```

So problem is, that the Window can still get moved outside of the area and it is lagging. I want to avoid this behavior by locking vertical or horizontal movement.

My solution approach would be catch a `PreviewMouseMove` or `PreviewDragMove` event. But I don't know how to do this. `PreviewDragMove` does not exist.

### Preview

[image: preview]

---

## Final working solution

### ChildWindow

```
    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Properties
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// True when when mouse is down on the dragmove area
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsMouseDownOnDrag { get; private set; }

    private Rectangle _PartDragMove;
    private Point _AnchorPoint;
    private bool _IsDragging;
    private Rect _DragMoveArea = Rect.Empty;

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Konstructor
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    private HtChildWindow()
    {
        Unloaded += _OnUnloaded;
        Loaded += _OnLoaded;
    }

    private void _OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        if(_DragMoveArea == Rect.Empty)
            _DragMoveArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    }

    private void _OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        if (_PartDragMove != null)
        {
            _PartDragMove.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= PartDragMove_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }
    }

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Overrides
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _PartDragMove = GetTemplateChild("PART_DragMove") as Rectangle;
        if (_PartDragMove != null)
        {
            _PartDragMove.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += PartDragMove_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseDownOnDrag)
        {
            _AnchorPoint = PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));
            _IsDragging = true;
            CaptureMouse();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_IsDragging)
        {
            Point currentPoint = PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));

            double newLeftPosition = Left + currentPoint.X - _AnchorPoint.X;
            double newTopPosition = Top + currentPoint.Y - _AnchorPoint.Y;

            //control area
            if (newLeftPosition < _DragMoveArea.X)
                newLeftPosition = _DragMoveArea.X;
            if (newTopPosition < _DragMoveArea.Y)
                newTopPosition = _DragMoveArea.Y;
            if(newLeftPosition + ActualWidth > _DragMoveArea.X + _DragMoveArea.Width)
                newLeftPosition = _DragMoveArea.X + _DragMoveArea.Width - ActualWidth;
            if (newTopPosition + ActualHeight > _DragMoveArea.Y + _DragMoveArea.Height)
                newTopPosition = _DragMoveArea.Y + _DragMoveArea.Height - ActualHeight;

            Left = newLeftPosition;
            Top = newTopPosition;
            _AnchorPoint = currentPoint;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseDownOnDrag = false;
        if (_IsDragging)
        {
            _IsDragging = false;
            e.Handled = true;
            ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
    }

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Events
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    private void PartDragMove_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        IsMouseDownOnDrag = true;
    }

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Public Methods
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    public void SetDragMoveArea(Rect area)
    {
        _DragMoveArea = area;
    }
```

So now I'm only calling `SetDragMoveArea()` if my `ChildWindow` should get *locked* inside of my `WindowContainer`.
I'm extracting the information for this area with the following code

```
WorkingArea = WindowContainer.TransformToAncestor(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), WindowContainer.RenderSize));
```

As default, is it locked inside of the `Screen` (See `_OnLoaded`).

### Preview of working solution

[image: Working_Preview]

Comment: There are no mouse drag events, because dragging is not something the mouse is concerned about. Hence why you don't find a mouse event about drag. Dragging a window is behavior of the window, not behavior of the mouse. You can implement your specific desired drag functionality by watching and tracking not only mouse coordinates, but also the state of the mouse button(s). This information is provided by mouse events.

Comment: I guess (and i am just guessing here), what you really want is to trap the mouse in a specific region, right? (I.e., the mouse should not disconnect from the window and move any further when the window hits an area boundary)

Comment: No I want to hold the ChildWindow inside of the WindowContainer. That (for example) the keyboard (preview) cannot be moved outside of the screen and it's always in the visible area.

Comment: That sounds like a yes to me. Or do you really want to restrict the window movement, but leave the mouse movement (during dragging) unrestricted?

Comment: A you're right! I had misunderstood you.

Comment: Just an idea (i really don't know if they would work out okay for you, though). Let the mouse be captured by the window container -- however, this will still let the window partially leave the container during dragging. Instead, create a (transparent) panel in the window container with a location and size of the desired capture are and let it capture the mouse. This child panel will receive the mouse events while it has captured the mouse. You will need to track these mouse events and move/change the location of your ChildWindow accordingly.

Comment: This should not cause noticeable lag. If lag is observed, something else is responsible for it; like for example something forcing the ChildWindow to completely redraw after a location change, or something else occupying the UI thread while dragging...

Comment: @Niko, DragMove is unfortunately not virtual :( The method also only enables/initiates the drag mode, it does not execute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution for you. If you want to customize movements you cannot use `DragMove` method. Instead you have to implement this functionality on your own, overriding the following three functions: `OnMouseLeftButtonDown`, `OnMouseMove` and `OnMouseLeftButtonUp`.
I have implemented something like that:

```
 protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            anchorPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            inDrag = true;
            CaptureMouse();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Where `anchorPoint` is the point that I am using for Binging window position, `inDrag` is private boolean and `CaptureMouse` is `UIElement` method.

And then:

```
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (inDrag)
        {
            Point currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            this.Left = this.Left + currentPoint.X - anchorPoint.X;
            /*this.Top = this.Top + currentPoint.Y - anchorPoint.Y*/; // this is not changing in your case
            anchorPoint = currentPoint;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (inDrag)
        {
            ReleaseMouseCapture();
            inDrag = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    // Loss of capture e.g. when you press Alt + Tab
    protected override void OnLostMouseCapture(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_inDrag)
        {
            ReleaseMouseCapture();
            _inDrag = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

where `ReleaseMouseCapture` is `UIElement` method.
I think it should help you.

Comment: Hey Niko. Thanks for your answer! It is almost the solution I need. I will update my post if I have completely implemented it.